# Parsing error when creating view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view which takes multiple rows and Comma Separated Values (CSV) from table columns with data.

It was working well and I got the results that I needed. Now the view has some parsing error like:

> Error in WHERE clause near '('. Unable to parse query text.

Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
SELECT dbo.table1.title,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), dbo.table3.uid) AS [text()]
              FROM   dbo.table2
                     INNER JOIN dbo.table3
                       ON dbo.table3.uid = dbo.table2.FK_Group
              WHERE  dbo.table3.uid = dbo.table2.FK_Group
                     AND dbo.table3.company = dbo.main.company
                     AND dbo.table2.FK_Version = dbo.table1.fk_Version
                     AND dbo.main_version.uid = dbo.table1.fk_Version
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS groupName
FROM   dbo.main_version
       INNER JOIN dbo.[main]
         ON dbo.version.fk_main = dbo.[main].uid
       INNER JOIN dbo.main_schema
         ON dbo.[main].fk_SCHEMA = dbo.main_schema.uid
       INNER JOIN dbo.table1
         ON dbo.version.uid = dbo.table1.fk_Version
WHERE  ( dbo.main_version.active = 1 )
```

Comment: Why do you have all those WHERE clauses on the `groupName` column? They should all be part of the INNER JOIN above it.

Comment: Is that causes the syntax issue?

Comment: I don't know, that's why this is a comment rather than answer - more of a pointer :-)

Comment: I have changed the code and tried as you said. But the issue still exists. :-)

Comment: If it was working before, what did you change to stop it working? The query above parses without error for me, so it's unlikely that this is really the view definition that you're working with